# PyFirmata doesn't respond after creating Arduino() object

Tags: python, arduino, python-module

I recently learnt about controlling arduino with python using PyFirmata.
I tried to write a code to make the builtin LED blink, but I receive no output after I create the Arduino() object. Here's my code:

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino
import time

arduino = Arduino("COM3")
num = int(input("How many times should the LED blink?"))
sleep_time = float(input("Time (seconds) between each blink (decimal values are allowed): "))
print(f"Blinking {num} times with a {sleep_time} second delay")

for temp in range(num):
    arduino.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)  # Seconds
    arduino.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

My Python version is 3.6.0, on Windows 10 (64-bit), I have included a screenshot of my code and my terminal.
[image: Here's a screenshot of my code and the terminal]

Also, to clarify, I am not receiving any error messages or any output otherwise. I don't even get a terminal prompt, the cursor just keeps blinking

EDIT: My Arduino board is a UNO, it is working properly with the Arduino IDE and using `.ino` programs.

Comment: Another clarification - even though VSCode shows an import error, I tried commenting everything except the `from pyfirmata import Arduino` line, and I get no errors. So I don't think that is the problem

Comment: You do have the Firmata sketch loaded onto your Arduino, right?

Comment: Oh no, I seem to have missed that. Uploaded and now it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:** I did not upload the Standard Firmata Sketch to the Arduino, which is required for pyFirmata to work. Thanks to @jasonharper for pointing this out :)

To upload the sketch, you will have to go to `File > Examples > Firmata` in Arduino IDE, select a firmata sketch from the list and click upload when it opens a new window.